# How to set dscp for incoming TCP connections to my server?

Tags: tcp, qos

I need to specify dscp settings for the incoming TCP connections to my server. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you run linux. With iptables you can specify the settings

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 21 -j DSCP --set-dscp 1
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 21 -s 192.168.0.0/24 --j DSCP --set-dscp-class EF
```

Comment: I was specifically asking os-agnostic because I didn't have a good idea about it - so this answer is great to get, because it helps me in my search. However, frankly, this was a Windows 2008 problem.